# JQuery .autocomplete and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

i have a little question.
I want to create a user friendly search, so i have to provide a function to auto complete the input.

My problem is, that there are more than 1 categories, so i want to write in autocomplete - dropdown:

**"CATEGORY"** "ARTICLE"

When i press on the item, CATEGORY + ARTICLE goes in my input field, but i only want to return the ARTICLE  name :)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<input id="tags" type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Suche Items, Quests, Gebiete und mehr !">
```

And here you can see my script (jQuery):

```js
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "<b>Community </b> Please help me.",
            "<b>Article </b> New update !",
            "<b>Community </b> A Question..."
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        //  source: availableTags
            
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        }
            
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
         return $("<li></li>")
             .data("item.autocomplete", item)
             .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
             .appendTo(ul);
     };
    });
```

I hope, you can understand, what i want to reach, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the `label` and `value` in your object and pass that to the autocomplete:

```
     var availableTags = 
      [
       {label:"Community", value: "Please Help Me"},
       {label:"Article", value: "New Update!"},
       {label:"Community", value: "A Question..."}
      ];
```

Then you can call `.label` and `value` on each item:

```
.append("<a><b>" + item.label + "</b>: " + item.value + "</a>")
```

Full code:

```
$(function() {
     var availableTags = 
      [
       {label:"Community", value: "Please Help Me"},
       {label:"Article", value: "New Update!"},
       {label:"Community", value: "A Question..."}
      ];

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        //  source: availableTags

        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        }

        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
         return $("<li></li>")
             .data("item.autocomplete", item)
             .append("<a><b>" + item.label + "</b>: " + item.value + "</a>")
             .appendTo(ul);
     };
    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cn17beym/)

**UPDATE**

The search appears to be on the `label` so you can Add the whole name for `label`, and set the `value` for what you want to be set as the input value:

```
var availableTags = [
     {label:"<b>Community</b>: Please Help Me", value: "Please Help Me"},
     {label:"<b>Article:</b> New Update!", value: "New Update!"},
     {label:"<b>Community:</b> A Question...", value: "A Question..."}
];
```

And Then:

```
.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cn17beym/2/)

Comment: works fine, but the search function is "buggy". When i type in "New", i find nothing, i have to type in a char included in the label, how can i fix this ?

Comment: @SebiPuck you can switch the `label` and the `value` since it appears it's searching by label. Edited my post

Comment: but when i do this, the wrong thing goes to the input box, right ?

Comment: @SebiPuck Yep, sorry, I updated it, now it should work